# Why integer.tryParse considering a null as a string?

Tags: vb.net

why integer.tryParse considering a null value as a string?
thanks

Dim x As Integer

```
    If Integer.TryParse(txtchange.Text, x) Then

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("'" + txtchange.Text + "' is not valid number")

    End If
```

Im getting another message box even its null already thanks

Comment: TextBox.Text *is* String.

Comment: how can i overcome it whenever I erase the values that it wont throw the message box? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an empty TextBox to be interpreted as zero, so check for that:

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
If txtchange.Text.Trim = String.Empty OrElse _
   Integer.TryParse(txtchange.Text, x) Then
  'ok to process "x"...
Else
  MessageBox.Show("'" + txtchange.Text + "' is not valid number")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using either [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(*.net 2.0 and greater*) or [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)(*.net 4.0 and greater*) before you  try to Parse your value.

```
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtchange.Text) Then
    If Not Integer.TryParse(txtchange.Text, x) Then
        MessageBox.Show("'" + txtchange.Text + "' is not valid number")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: @user3417541: If this answer was helpful, please accept it.